# roslaunch and NVidia profiling

Tags: roslaunch, ros-kinetic, ubuntu, ubuntu-xenial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Has anyone had any success getting NVidia profiling tools and ROS to play well together?

At the moment, the best I can do is profile all processes, but that only reports memory copies to and from host, and some OpenCV (copy to and from `cv::Mat` and `cv::cuda::GpuMat`). My custom kernels are never profiled (yes, I have explicit `cudaProfilerStart()/Stop()` calls) and trying to use `launch-prefix="nvprof"` or directly profiling `roslaunch` never gets me anywhere except errors about being unable to load some nodelets.

Any suggestions as to what I might be doing wrong? I'm on Ubuntu 16.04.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/302417/roslaunch-and-nvidia-profiling/) by [KenYN](https://answers.ros.org/users/25651/kenyn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 541 on 2018-09-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2018-09-05**:
Are you running cuda code within nodelets? If your cuda code is running within a nodelet, you may want to try running nvprof on the nodelet manager.

**Comment by [KenYN](https://answers.ros.org/users/25651/kenyn/) on 2018-09-05**:
I've tried that too, but no joy. I even have my `cudaProfilerStart()` called from every thread within the nodelet. Once or twice I have actually managed to capture calls to my CUDA code, but I've never managed to reproduce that...

**Comment by [KenYN](https://answers.ros.org/users/25651/kenyn/) on 2018-09-05**:
Ah, I've tried again and just noticed an error about being unable to activate Unified Memory Profiling, so using `launch-prefix="nvprof --unified-memory-profiling off"` gets me further than I've ever got before.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-09-05**:
@KenYN: what was the answer here? Your last comment?

If so: please post that as an answer and then accept your own answer.

We don't really close questions here on ROS Answers when they have an actual answer.

**Comment by [KenYN](https://answers.ros.org/users/25651/kenyn/) on 2018-09-05**:
@gvdhoorn Oops, I cannot re-open. Can someone else please? I also discovered how to get final output, so I can actually answer the question now.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-09-05**:
I've re-opened it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I finally managed to get output, but not very prettily...

In my manager `node` line, I added `launch-prefix="nvprof --unified-memory-profiling off --profile-child-process --profile-from-start off"`. Then in a suitable callback I added the following:

```
static bool startedProfile = false;
void MyClass::image_cb(const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr image)
{
    if (!startedProfile)
    {
        startedProfile = true;
        cudaProfilerStart();
    }
    else if (startedProfile && image->header.seq > 400) // 400 frames is enough profiling
    {
        cudaProfilerStop();
        cudaDeviceReset();
        exit(0);
    }

    // Existing code...
}
```

This is a *very* ugly way to finish profiling, but `cudaProfilerStop()` on its own didn't produce any output and neither did the addition of `exit(0)`. There are other nodelets running other CUDA code on both the same and different GPUs, so perhaps we needed to force every CUDA process to stop to get the profiling results to output?

---

Originally posted by [KenYN](https://answers.ros.org/users/25651/kenyn/) with karma: 541 on 2018-09-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just in case you have troubles with this as i did. You need sudo for profiling CUDA GPUs. Just adding sudo in front unfortunatelly does not work, as sudo users have different envrionment variables. ROS commands are not be available in the sudo environment. What worked for me is:

1. sudo -s
2. nvprof --output-profile ./profile.dat '/home/ma/catkin_ws/devel/lib/YOUR_PKG/YOUR_NODE' --profile-from-start off

If this still does not work, try to source the .bashrc after the first step. Btw. if you open the profile.dat in the NVIDiA visual profiler (nvvp) you get a very nice timeline. You can only open the file if the profiler comes from the same CUDA version as nvprof.
Good luck!

---

Originally posted by [look001](https://answers.ros.org/users/83196/look001/) with karma: 11 on 2021-09-01

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1